# Error in edit preview functionality when using tabs in a code block

Tags: bug, markdown-preview

There is a problem with the edit preview. For example, edit [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31476046/2377343)
and see this error:

[image]

Comment: The bug seems to be triggered by the presence of the `$` character earlier on the line; replacing it with something else fixes it. Investigating further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this bug is triggered by the presence of `$` or `~` earlier on the line.  In fact, I found the code in [wmd.en.js](http://meta.dev.stackexchange.com/content/Js/wmd.en.js) that triggers it:

```js
// attacklab: Replace ~ with ~T
// This lets us use tilde as an escape char to avoid md5 hashes
// The choice of character is arbitray; anything that isn't
// magic in Markdown will work.
text = text.replace(/~/g, "~T");

// attacklab: Replace $ with ~D
// RegExp interprets $ as a special character
// when it's in a replacement string
text = text.replace(/\$/g, "~D");

// ...SNIP...

// Convert all tabs to spaces.
text = _Detab(text);

// ...SNIP...

text = _RunBlockGamut(text);

text = _UnescapeSpecialChars(text);

// attacklab: Restore dollar signs
text = text.replace(/~D/g, "$$");

// attacklab: Restore tildes
text = text.replace(/~T/g, "~");
```

(*Ed. note: some irrelevant code replaced by `// ...SNIP...` markers for brevity.*)

The `_Detab()` function (which is also called indirectly by `_RunBlockGamut()` via `_DoCodeBlocks()`; I'm not sure *why* this is done twice) isn't aware of the fact that `~T` and `~D` should be counted as single characters, so it's miscalculating the length of any strings that contain those escape sequences, and thus getting the tab stops wrong for lines that contain them.

Presumably, the proper fix would be to make `_Detab()` aware of the tilde-escaping convention, so that it can count such escape sequences correctly.

In fact, here's a tentative (untested) patch to fix this:

```js
--- wmd.en.js   2015-08-26 16:32:34.930482439 +0300
+++ wmd.en.new.js   2015-08-26 16:42:00.030476026 +0300
@@ -1586,11 +1586,16 @@
             skew = 0,
             v;

-            return text.replace(/[\n\t]/g, function (match, offset) {
+            return text.replace(/[\n\t~]/g, function (match, offset) {
                 if (match === "\n") {
                     skew = offset + 1;
                     return match;
                 }
+                // count ~T and ~D as only one character each: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260882/error-in-edit-preview-functionality-when-using-tabs-in-a-code-block
+                if (match === "~") {
+                    skew++;
+                    return match;
+                }
                 v = (offset - skew) % 4;
                 skew = offset + 1;
                 return spaces[v];
```

(The patch is generated against the combined wmd.en.js file, but it should apply against the internal Markdown.Converter.js with a slight offset.)